# Java split string to array

Tags: java, string, split

I need help with the `split()` method. 
I have the following`String`:

```
String values = "0|0|0|1|||0|1|0|||";
```

I need to put the values into an array. There are 3 possible strings: "0", "1", and ""

My problem is, when i try to use `split()`:

```
String[] array = values.split("\\|");
```

My values are saved only until the last 0. Seems like the part "|||" gets trimmed.
What am i doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 155, accepted):

This behavior is explicitly documented in [`String.split(String regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) (emphasis mine):

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. **Trailing empty strings** are therefore **not included** in the resulting array.

If you want those trailing empty strings included, you need to use [`String.split(String regex, int limit)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) with a negative value for the second parameter (`limit`):

```
String[] array = values.split("\\|", -1);
```

Comment: Thank, thats exactly what I needed.
String array[] = myValues.split("\\|", -1);

Answer (score 26):

Try this

```
String[] array = values.split("\\|",-1);
```

Answer (score 13):

Consider this example:

```
public class StringSplit {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    String testString = "Real|How|To|||";
    System.out.println
       (java.util.Arrays.toString(testString.split("\\|")));
    // output : [Real, How, To]
  }
}
```

The result does not include the empty strings between the "|" separator. To keep the empty strings :

```
public class StringSplit {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    String testString = "Real|How|To|||";
    System.out.println
       (java.util.Arrays.toString(testString.split("\\|", -1)));
    // output : [Real, How, To, , , ]
  }
}
```

For more details go to this website: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0438.html

Answer (score 1):

This is expected.
Refer to [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) for `split`.

```
Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.
```

This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split(java.lang.String,int) method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. **Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.**