# Java - String splits by every character

Tags: java, split

When I try to split a string with a delimiter "|", it seems to split every single character.

This is my line which is causing the problem:

```
String out = myString.split("|");
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In regex, `|` is a reserved character used for [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html). You need to escape it:

```
String out = string.split("\\|");
```

Note that we used two backslashes. This is because the first one escapes the second one in the Java string, so the string passed to the regex engine is `\|`.

Comment: Oh thanks! I thought one would escape it with one backslash but Android Studio told me it was an illegal escape character so I assumed it didn't need escaping. Thanks!

Comment: To clarify, it's not that the `|` character means an empty string. It means "or." It's just that this means that the regex in the question translates to "an empty string or an empty string."

Comment: @Yharoomanner Note that the double backslash represents a backslash character in the input string. This is then passed to the regex parser as the string "\|" which represents a vertical bar character.

Answer (score 1):

I think this was already answered in [Java split string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414582/java-split-string-to-array)

In summary of the answers in the link above:

```
String[] array = values.split("\\|",-1);
```

This is because:

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument `split` method with the given expression and a `limit` argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

Answer (score 1):

`split` takes a regular expression, in which `|` is a special character. You need to escape it with a backslash. But the backslash is a special character in Java strings, so you need to escape that, too.

```
myString.split("\\|")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it worked for me!

```
 String tivoServiceCodes = "D1FAMN,DTV|SKYSP1,DTV|MOV01,VOD";
    String[] serviceCodes = tivoServiceCodes.split("\\|");
    for(String sc : serviceCodes){
        System.out.println(sc.toString());
    }
```