# Java - How to split a string with numbers separated by spaces into variables?

Tags: java, split, integer

I am given the string "23 45" I need to get 2 variables (int a) with the value 23 and (int b) with value 45

Comment: What does "splitting a string into variables" mean?  Can you provide an example?

Comment: This is almost exactly the same except the separating character is `|` instead of space: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414582/java-split-string-to-array

Answer (score 5):

if your input String name is ' **in** ' , then we will have :

```
String in = "23 45";

String s[] = in.split(" "); 

int out[] = new int[s.length]; 

for(int i = 0 ; i < s.length ; i++) 

     out[i] = Integer.parseInt(s[i]);
```

output is now in out array