# Regex to find the first occurence of first 8 digits from a string in Java

Tags: java, regex

Here is my String **20161011** , I wanted to get the first String **20161011**.

I am using the `(^|\\s)([0-9]+)($|\\s)` , however it doesn't work, could someone suggest the correct usage, btw the first String I wanted to retrieve is a date of the format **yyyymmdd** , I don't need to validate the date format as it comes pre validated.

Comment: What code are you using to test the regex?

Comment: For many regex implementations you can use `{n}` to denote "n times". Eg `[0-9]{8}` would get 8 decimal digits

Comment: No offense, but what's wrong with `substring`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you what you want:

```
^([0-9]{8}).*
```

- ^              : matches the beginning of the line
- ([0-9]{8})     : matches and captures the first 8 numeric digits
- .*             : matches the rest of the string and does not capture it. (you
  could probably leave this part off)

Answer (score 1):

The regex `$(\d{8})\.` would work on your sample. However, it's possible that you really want to split the string as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414582/java-split-string-to-array). This would give you access to each number, not just the first. It's also probably a bit faster.

Comment: My String changes dynamically each time, in the next occurence it may be 201610110909201 in the event that I am only interested with the first 8 digits from the string always

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can achieve this,

```
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile("\\d{8}+");
    Matcher m = r.matcher("12345678.231610.01234567");
    String str = "";
    if (m.find()) {
        // Only stores first occurence, occuring at any index of string.
        str = m.group();
    }
```