# Why do you get the different sized arrays from invoking split() on an empty string and a string which consists of only separators

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

After you split an empty string, you get an array of 1 element 
After you split a string that have only separators/delimiters(for example, only special characters which the split(\W) will remove), you get an array of 0 elements?

They both lead to empty tokens so surely they have the same length arrays? 
But why not?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414582/java-split-string-to-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because, split have two case:

1. If no match was found, return `new String[] { this }`, for example:

   ```
   "1111".split(",") // {"1111"}
   " ".split(",") // {" "}
   "".split(",") // {""}
   ```
2. It match was found, return `new String[resultSegmentCount]`, when `resultSegmentCount = 0`, for example:

   ```
    " , ".split(",") // {" ", " "}
    " ,".split(",") // {" "}
    ", ".split(",") // {" "}
    ",".split(",") // {}
   ```

Comment: You can see the current source code of the `String.split(String, int)` method [at grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java#String.split%28java.lang.String%2Cint%29). Note that `String.split(String)` simply calls `String.split(String, int)` with an integer argument of zero.