# Splitting String from a specific pattern

Tags: java, string

How could I turn this String into two different variables from a pattern?

String: `"[ADDRESS] Custom address n 1"`
Variable ***type*** would be `"ADDRESS"` and variable ***field*** would be `"Custom address n 1"`.
Is it possible without having a complicated loop checking for each character?

Comment: Use regex parsing. One way would be to use a regex to parse the string into two groups, one containing "[...] " and the other containing the rest. Then you would be able to extract the parts into whatever you wish.

Comment: `"ADDRESS Custom address n 1".split(" ", 2)`

Comment: `type` = anything inside `[]` (excluding them). `field` = the rest

Comment: Use simple regex to get the info from the pattern. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49246669/using-split-method-in-java-to-separate-different-inputs/49265943#49265943

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use regex with capturing groups:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*)\\] (.*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("[ADDRESS] Custom address n 1");
if (m.find()) {
    String type = m.group(1);
    String field = m.group(2);
}
```

Comment: @Andreas Would `.*?` have the same benefit?

Comment: @shmosel No, but better than `.*`, since `.*` goes all the way to the end, then backtracks from there. According to regex101, `\[(.*)\] (.*)` is 50 steps, `\[(.*?)\] (.*)` is 24 steps, and `\[([^\]]*)\] (.*)` is 10 steps.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using this regex:

```
\[([^\]]*)\](.*)
```

For the String `"[ADDRESS] Custom address n 1"`,

- Group 1 would be "ADDRESS"
- Group 2 would be "Custom address n 1"