# How to get the comma seperated values from the excel cell sheet using java code

Tags: java

I am unable to get the comma separated values from the excel cell using java code.

I had tried using the following code also.

```
String [] items = commaSeparated.split("\\s*,\\s*");
List<String> container = Arrays.asList(items);
```

I want the output as a list like:

```
IND
PAK
USA
AUS
```

When the input is imported from the Excel cell as IND,PAK,USA,AUS.

Comment: The context of your question doesn't seem to make sense. We'll need more code, like statements for reading the Excel file and the contents of that Excel cell.

Comment: how about string.split(' IND,PAK,USA,AUS',',')

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java split string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414582/java-split-string-to-array)

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is print each item of your CSV data on a new line, this code will do the job.

```
    String csvLine = "IND,PAK,USA,AUS";
    Arrays.stream(csvLine.split(",")).forEach(
            item -> System.out.println(item)
    );
```