# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1 when trying to read csv

Tags: java, android, opencsv

I have problem when trying to read the csv file, the error appears like this : `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1` . I have tried searching in StackOverflow, the error appears same as above.

Code :

```
private void readCSVFile(String csvNameFile) {
    try {
        File readFolderCSV = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/" + csvNameFile);
        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(readFolderCSV.getAbsoluteFile()));
        String[] nextLine;
        while((nextLine = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
            Log.e("TAG", nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] + nextLine[2] + nextLine[3] + nextLine[4]);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(MasterUoM.this, "The specified file was not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

MyCSVFile :

[image: 1]

Comment: That means you only have one item in that array (at index 0) but you are trying to access a second one (index 1). So, most likely, `nextLine[1]` causes the `Exception` because there is only one `String` in it (the entire line, maybe?).

Comment: Based on your screenshot, it seems there are only going to be only 2 objects in your nextLine[] array. So the nextLine[2] or above should give an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException as expected.

Comment: Your `csv` contains only 2 columns in each row, but  you try to get 3, 4, 5 which cause the exception

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman MyCSVFile just an example. How about when i have much data of Categories Name in Category Name column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to fetch column[2] and column[3] & column[4] but csv is not having 5 columns,

```
 Log.e("TAG", nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] + nextLine[2] + nextLine[3] + nextLine[4]);
```

You can check it by printing nextLine.length().

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have checked with nextLine.length and the result is 1. Then i have tried to change nextLine[0] and the result is success. Big thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
while((nextLine = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
            Log.e("TAG", nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] + nextLine[2] + nextLine[3] + nextLine[4]);
        }
```

Your are logging without length safety. You have a line where `nextLine[1]` does not exist. That's because csvreader does not return cells but lines.

You need to split the line using the split method. [Java split string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414582/java-split-string-to-array) and again check if the length of the table is enough.

3,4 and 5 cell access will cause you the same trouble.